# Compare values in different template parts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

For certain reasons I have to add a bit of style (margin) to the footer of the page. It should only be applied when the content part of the page is a product archive.

I tried to create a variable in the archive-products.php file like this:

```
<?php global $template;

$template = 'prodarchive';

var_dump($template);?>
```

According to the var_dump the value is set. Next I tried to call it in my footer.php like this

```
<?php if ($template === 'prodarchive' ) {?>
```

and then the stuff it needs to do.

Some tests shows me that the footer.php file is not able to reproduce the value of $template. What is wrong?

Comment: The easiest solution is @seemly's answer below, but you can also use `is_post_type_archive('product')`, which returns a bool value. As to why your global variable isn't working in `footer.php`, I'm pretty sure `get_footer()` doesn't actually pass all global variables.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I am using your suggestion like this: `<?php if (is_post_type_archive('product') || is_archive('product')) {?>`. Works like a charm on all product archive pages. When you post it as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution (as pointed out by @seemly) is to apply the `body_class()` function to the `<body>` tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This will apply a range useful  classes that you can use for CSS, including one of the product archive pages.

Another approach is to use `is_post_type_archive('product')`, which returns a boolean value.

As to why your global variable isn't working in footer.php, I'm pretty sure `get_footer()` isn't passed all global variables when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Is the post type not applied as a css class to the body tag?

If not, you can add it to the array of classes that get applied to the body tag, and base any additional styling from that.

[How to add classes to body tag](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-to-the-body-class-in-wordpress--cms-21077)

Comment: It would be good if you put the actual function in your answer, in case that link stops working in the future.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I went for the solution in the comment of Dre. I'm using `<?php if (is_post_type_archive('product') || is_archive('product')) {?>` and it works fine on the shop page, the category pages and the search archives.